# How the browser plug-in does the computation?

Tags: javascript, web, browser, plugins, computation

Suppose, I have installed a browser plug-in/extension in my browser. This plug-in needs to do the computation based on the metadata of a webpage. So, does that use the memory of the user's system for computation? Or some other server like entity is used for computation?

Comment: That would depend on how the browser plugin is programmed.  If it's programmed to use the memory of the user's system for computation, it does that.  If it's programmed to do a Remote Procedure Call on some server halfway around the world, it does that.

Comment: So, which is preferable in practice, if I want to do the computation in minimal time? My guess is that using user's system would help in saving the request/response time.

Comment: That would depend on whether you're doing a highly-focused, localized calculation that is suitable for a local machine, or a complex, highly-distributed calculation that involves several different computing resources spread out over the Internet.